# Convert x and y coordinates of an image to a row-major linear index

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, coordinates, pixel

Suppose I have an image of size 600 x 400 and I know the (x,y) coordinate of a point in the image. I have another output that is a single 1D array obtained from the same image which has 600*400 = 240000 values which contains the pixels unrolled in row-major order. I need to map the (x,y) coordinate to its corresponding location.

```
I tried the equation pixel = (y-1)*width + x
```

Is this the right way to map coordinates to corresponding index?

Comment: this cannot be answered. how are we supposed to know how the values in your "other output" are ordered?

Comment: Mr.Piglet, its ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right line of thinking here.  You are producing a row-major linear index for each location in the image.  OpenCV (and ultimately NumPy arrays as that is what is used to process images with the OpenCV library in Python) lays out the image data in row-major form.  However your expression is not quite correct, but you are very close.`(y-1)*width + x` assumes that the coordinates start at **1**.  Because the coordinates start at **0** in OpenCV instead of 1, it should be just `y*width + x`.  I will leave it as an exercise for you to discover that this is correct.

Comment: Hi @rayryeng thanks for your response. As you mentioned the coordinate starts at 0 and the pixel indexes are represented as 0 to 239999. I will check with y*width + x and get back to you. Thank you